# Executable jar file final class constructor not running

Tags: java, swing

I have java standalone application,i created jar file in eclipse,when i run the jar file the main method executed in the main method declared the final class(this final class constructor not called when i run the jar).

here i mentioned the main method code.

```
final PLTaxEst2014 f = new PLTaxEst2014();
final boolean IsMaxed = true;
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "hiiiiiiiiiiii"
                        , "Registration Succeeded", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                if (f.closeBeforeOpen) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "closed"
                            , "Registration Succeeded", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    f.finalShutdown(false);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "else"
                            , "Registration Succeeded", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    f.setTitle(f.getClass().getSimpleName());
                    //instead of standard EXIT_ON_CLOSE, do nothing so can cancel.
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.setSize(800, 600);
                    f.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
                        "bitmaps/PLicon32B.gif")).getImage());
                    if (IsMaxed) f.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                    f.checkRegularAfterLoad();
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

please help me!!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is your `main()` method being called? You say that the code example is of the `main()` method but I don't see the declaration of the `main()` method. Could you show a bit more of code?

Comment: By the way: if you are not sure whether some point the application is executed, just put some `System.out.println("1");` (with different numbers) in your code. From these messages you can see which parts are and which parts are not executed.

Comment: when i run it from eclipse the PLTaxEst2014 class constructor calling and working fine.i generate the jar,when i run the jar main method executed  but PLTaxEst2014 class constructor not calling,app not running.

Comment: Can you show me the command you use to run the code in the jar file? And could you show the run configuration in Eclipse?

Comment: i am not using any command to run the jar,just double clicking on it.

Comment: Are you sure that the main class is mentioned in the manifest inside the jar file? If not sure, can you unzip the jar file and put the contents of the manifest file here?

Comment: i am not creating any manifest file while creating the jar file.how can i do this?

Comment: Check out http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-35.htm